# Rotated Image gets distorted and blurry?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-graphics

I use an image view:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
```

to paint an image and also another image which has been rotated. It turns out that the rotated image has very bad quality. In the following image the glasses in the yellow box are not rotated. The glasses in the red box are rotated by 4.39 degrees.

[image]

Here is the code I use to draw the glasses:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.image!.size)
    imageView.image!.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.image!.size.width, imageView.image!.size.height))

var drawCtxt = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

var glassImage = UIImage(named: "glasses.png")
let yellowRect = CGRect(...)

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(drawCtxt, UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor)
CGContextStrokeRect(drawCtxt, yellowRect)
CGContextDrawImage(drawCtxt, yellowRect, glassImage!.CGImage)

// paint the rotated glasses in the red square
CGContextSaveGState(drawCtxt)
CGContextTranslateCTM(drawCtxt, centerX, centerY)
CGContextRotateCTM(drawCtxt, 4.398 * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180)
var newRect = yellowRect
newRect.origin.x = -newRect.size.width / 2
newRect.origin.y = -newRect.size.height / 2
CGContextAddRect(drawCtxt, newRect)
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(drawCtxt, UIColor.redColor().CGColor)
CGContextSetLineWidth(drawCtxt, 1)

// draw the red rect
CGContextStrokeRect(drawCtxt, newRect)
// draw the image
CGContextDrawImage(drawCtxt, newRect, glassImage!.CGImage)
CGContextRestoreGState(drawCtxt)
```

How can I rotate and paint the glasses without losing quality or get a distorted image?

Comment: Does it help if you create the context with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(..., 0.0)` to get a drawing context that uses the same scaling factor as your device?

Comment: @MartinR which size should I use to generate the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize size, BOOL opaque, CGFloat scale)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) to create the initial context.  Passing in `0.0` as the `scale` will default to the scale of the current screen (e.g., `2.0` on an iPhone 6 and `3.0` on an iPhone 6 Plus).

See this note on `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()`:

> This function is equivalent to calling the UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions function with the opaque parameter set to NO and a scale factor of 1.0.

Comment: What does the ``opaque`` parameter do? I did not see any difference.

Comment: Docs: "If you know the bitmap is fully opaque, specify `YES` to ignore the alpha channel and optimize the bitmap’s storage. Specifying `NO` means that the bitmap must include an alpha channel to handle any partially transparent pixels."

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you need to set up your context to allow for retina displays.

Aside from that, you might want to use a source image that is larger than the target display size and scale it down. (2X the pixel dimensions of the target image would be a good place to start.)

Rotating to odd angles is destructive. The graphics engine has to map a grid of source pixels onto a different grid where they don't line up. Perfectly straight lines in the source image are no longer straight in the destination image, etc. The graphics engine has to do some interpolation, and a source pixel might be spread over several pixels, or less than a full pixel, in the destination image.

By providing a larger source image you give the graphics engine more information to work with. It can better slice and dice those source pixels into the destination grid of pixels.